# Copy/Paste Chinese character into SQL2005, displays as box

Tags: sql-server, localization

If I pull a character from one of the unicode character maps found on google and copy/paste that into SQL2005 it just displays as just a white box. The data is there because when I load the string into my app it displays as Chinese characters again, except in certain cases I am still seeing boxes in my app so that is why I need to get to the bottom of why I am seeing them in SQL2005. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

SSMS uses different fonts for the SQL Editor and Result Set panes.

If you write TSQL such as

```
DECLARE @d nvarchar(10)  = N'' ;
SELECT @d;
```

the character (U+2317F not in the BMP) is displayed as white box in the editor, but the results tab displays it correctly (tested with SSMS 2008).

The same may apply to your app: not all Chinese characters are included in every font.

In the case of

```
DECLARE @d nvarchar(10)  = N'漢字' ;
SELECT @d;
```

the characters (BMP) are always displayed correctly.

Comment: Well I tried copying the second set of code (that should always display correctly) into a query window and upon pasting it the Chinese characters are replaced with red boxes. Same for selecting the boxes from a table, they still are boxes. I am using SSMS2005, does that make a difference?

Comment: There may be a difference, since MSSQL2005 supports Unicode 3.2, whereas 2008 supports 5.0. http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/12/13/unicode-versions-supported-in-sql-server/